# Checking if variable is Long or Double

Tags: java

Is there any way to check if the varible is Double or Long before doing anything with it?
Sometimes the Objects are Double and some they are Long. How can I check it before using it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
if (obj instanceof Double) ...
```

Comment: and is it possible to cast an Object Long to Double?

Comment: @Adriano: If you want the value of a `Long` as a `Double`, just use `Double doubleValue = longValue.doubleValue()`.

Comment: `toString()` would work, sure, but you're going through a completely unnecessary and imprecise intermediate form of the data. The `Number` class (that `Double` and `Long` are both subclasses of) provides methods _specifically designed_ for converting a value from one type of number to another... you should use them. `toString()` is intended to get a `String` representation, typically for _displaying_ something, and should not be used for anything else.

Answer (score 6):

You could use `instanceof`.

```
public void someMethod(Object o)
{
    if ( o instanceof Long )
    {
        // do stuff
    }
    else if ( o instanceof Double )
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: @khachik - I thought I had some reason to not use `else`, but I was probably tired. Thanks.